# Dividing by dominant term - can we always apply the Combination Rules for convergent sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

In a book I'm reading they introduced the usual "Combination Rules for convergent sequences" like so:

> If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = l$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = m$, then:
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n + b_n) = l + m$$
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} k a_n = kl$$
> ... etc.

Next, they introduced a way how to enable applying these rules to more complex algebraic fractions in order to find its limit.

The idea is, for a given fraction, divide the numerator and denominator by the *dominant* term.
Then, we can find the limit of the simpler result.

Example:

Given is $a_n = \frac{(2n+1)(n+2)}{3n^2 + 3n}$ for $n=1, 2, ...$. The dominant term is $n^2$, then divide in the numerator and denominator by $n^2$ and find:

$$a_n = \frac{(2n+1)(n+2)}{3n^2 + 3n} = \frac{(2+1/n)(1+2/n)}{3+3/n}$$

Then we can apply the combination rules to find

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \frac{(2+0)(1+0)}{(3+0)} = \frac{2}{3}$.

---

What I don't fully understand:

- In the definition of these combination rules, we assume that the limits of the sequences we combine exist, since we say: "If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = l$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = m$, then: ..."
- To my understanding, for a given algebraic fraction the limit might or might not exist.

Therefore:

- As described in the strategy above, we divide through by the dominant term - but how does this ensure that we fulfill the prerequisites that we need in order to apply the combination rules (limits exist)?
- Couldn't there be an algebraic fraction which still doesn't have a limit even after dividing by the dominant term?
  In such case, we still couldn't apply these combination rules in my view.

I think my question boils down to: Can I just always find the dominant term, divide the algebraic fraction by it and expect to find a useful limit?

Comment: If it contains polynomials only then the answer is *yes*

Comment: I recommend not thinking of it as an algorithm that must always work (precisely because of your questions). Think of it as a strategy that often leads to a solution; and if it gets stuck, you're learning other strategies to try afterwards.

Comment: Fair point @GregMartin - is there an example where it wouldn't work? I was trying to come up with an example that'd fail but I wasn't really sure what that could be in real numbers

Comment: Perhaps $\frac{n^2\sin n}{n^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the product, quotient, sum, scalar, $\dots$ properties only apply to convergent sequences, and the statement $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=l$ says both that $a_n$ is a convergent sequence and that $a_n$ converges to $l$.

If $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \cdot b_n =1$ but the limit of $b_n$ does not exist.

If $a_n=n$ and $b_n=-n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n +b_n=0$ but the limit of neither $a_n$ nor $b_n$ exist.

By using the phrase dominant term, I am assuming you mean rational functions for algebraic functions. The dominant term is the highest degree of a monomial in either polynomial of the quotient and this aligns with dividing by the largest power of $n$ in your example.

A rational function has a horizontal asymptote, or limit at infinity, if and only if the degree of the polynomial in the numerator, dividend, is at most the degree of the polynomial in the denominator, divisor.  If the dividend has a larger degree then you can examine the quotient and remainder to show divergence.

Dividing by the dominant term is equivalent to multiplying by the convergent sequence $d_n=(1/n^k)/(1/n^k)=1$. Since multiplying by 1 gives the same sequence, the existence of a limit is invariant whether you divide by the dominant term.

As we saw earlier, the converse of the properties are false. Meaning, if we break your example into a product of three sequences, $$(2n+1) \cdot (n+2) \cdot \frac{1}{3n^2+3n}$$ we see that, individually, two of these factor sequences are divergent, but this does not mean that the product diverges. If  we multiply by $1=(1/n^2)/(1/n^2)$, out of cleverness with rational functions not because this is a technique that works in general, we get $$(2+1/n) \cdot (1+2/n) \cdot \frac{1}{3+3/n}$$ a product of three sequences that are convergent individually. In this form, the properties tell us that the limit is 2/3.